# What is the best way to filter/sort or manipulate data to be presented in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-services

I have a set of resources  (in JSON format) that I receive from a service.
The resources have properties like name, which operator they belong to, status, power flow etc.
First I select the operator from a drop down, or the status of the resources from another drop down.
Then I display the resources either as an array/map or list.
Then I sort them as per serial number or status, and I finally use color to distinguish between properties like status, power flow, state of charge etc.
Finally, these resources are displayed as per the options selected. I'm attaching a small picture.
[the view results when TSO(Operator)= Any, Array View, Serial sort and Status selected for identifying color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lOncT.png)

What is the best way to go about implementing this? I was thinking using routing where each selector has child routes embedded inside it and ultimately leads you to the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the way your filters work. Are they AND or OR filters? Can you make set than one filter? I assume you could pick both TSO *and* status.

In any case, I would keep filters in one component - regardless if you allow both or just one. You can reflect any filter changes in the router state. So, with filters component you decide **what** you are showing.

The results table could be a different (child?) component, as you suggest, and it subscribes to state (route) changes and updates the dataset accordingly.

The *view*, *order* and *sort* should be, I think, part of the display component, not the filter component. How you sort the results, how you color some of them, or even what manner you display them in, that's **how** you are showing the results, not **what**.

So that's a basic layout - Filter component decides on which data, and the Display component decides on how to present the data, and you use router for managing the state.

Comment: The choice in the first case is either between a TSO or status.What if I wanted to implement the same thing by creating classes? I'm not really sure how I would structure it. Any suggestions there?

Comment: Well, yes, you can setup one component with filters - maybe simple arrays, maybe something different depending what you have for TSOs or statuses.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions :)